# Remove empty lines in a CSV file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use powershell to export rest API to CSV with the following code

```
$DesiredProperties | Export-CSV -Path ".\Testrestapi.csv" -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation
```

It outputs the following to CSV:

```
,
"105283","TickerID"
"2365512290","TickerID"
,
,
,
,
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
,
,
,
,
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
"2121687888","TickerID"
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
,
```

Desired result:

```
"105283","TickerID"
"2365512290","TickerID"
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
"2121687888","TickerID"
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
```

I tried using

```
(gc file.txt) | ? {$_.Trim() -ne ""} | Set-Content file.txt
```

but it seems it is not working for CSV files. Could someone please show me which command I should be using in this script to remove empty lines ", , , ,"

Comment: What is `$DesiredProperties` ? Is it content from a file ?

Comment: `? {$_.Trim() -ne ""}` -> `? {$_.Trim(',')}`

Comment: Yes. In this case tickercode, ticker_code_type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Where-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -ne '' }` to clean up the `$DesiredProperties` object directly.

Example:

> Input data: "C:\Temp\Testrestapi.csv" (I use your CSV here, but you should take your export object from the REST API directly:

```
,
"105283","TickerID"
"2365512290","TickerID"
,
,
,
,
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
,
,
,
,
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
"2121687888","TickerID"
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
,
```

Sample code:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Testrestapi.csv" -Header 'col1','col2' | Where-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -ne '' } | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Testrestapi_clean.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

> Output data: "C:\Temp\Testrestapi_clean.csv":

```
"col1","col2"
"105283","TickerID"
"2365512290","TickerID"
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
"2121687888","TickerID"
"US594918AH79","ISIN"
```